# Bernoulli equivalent to the covariance matrix

Tags: image-processing, bernoulli-distribution

I'm looking for a parametric model for the density of binary variables. Say, a few hundred.

For continous variables I there is the Gaussian model. I can estimate mean and covariance matrix from data. If data is scarce, I can assume (using my prior knowledge) that the variables are mostly independent and focus learning on the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix.

Is there an equivalent for discrete variables? Sure, I can use an independent Bernoulli distribution for each parameter (the simple model). Or I can learn a separate probability for every possible permutation (a huge categorical distribution), which completely disregards my prior knowledge that the variables are probably independent.

Is there a method (or a distribution) that can blend between those two extremes?

#### Use Case

I'm asking in general, but to make this more concrete, I'll describe my toy problem that I'm working on.

The binary variables are defining a 2D look-up table that will be used to filter a black and white 2D image in multiple steps, similar to [dilation and erosion](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm). The density model is used to keep track of a distribution of "good" filters, and the parameters of the density are evolved using the [Cross-Entropy Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy_method) towards some fitness criteria. (E.g. to smooth the edges while maintaining a similar overall brightness, etc.). Random filters are sampled from the distribution and evaluated. The best 1% will be used to estimate the new parameters of the distribution.

Currently my parameters are just, for each input pattern, the probabilities that the output should be black. But clearly the best 1% filters will have some correlations. For example, maybe there is a pair of parameters of which  exactly one should be black, but it's not yet clear which one. I'm looking for a distribution that could model such a dependency.

Comment: There are a huge number of ways to model such things.  Ordinarily, then, one selects a model based on some theory--if only speculative--about the data generation process or expected behavior of the data.  Asking about "a few hundred binary variables" just doesn't give us sufficient information to provide well reasoned or useful recommendations.  Could you supply some hints at least?

Comment: I have added a description of my use-case. I was hoping there was just some simple distribution I've overlooked, but maybe it's not that easy.